# trunc(date) always give an error

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Hiii

look at this request and tell me why always Oracle give me this error

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
```

note 1 : that when I remove `TRUNK()` it's work but I went to put it on the request

note 2 : I use this date format `1/07/2014` or `1-07-2014` and `1/JUL/2014` always the same error

that's my request

```
  SELECT 
  QTYORDERED,
  LINENETAMT
FROM C_Orderline
INNER JOIN C_Order
ON (C_Orderline.C_Order_ID     = C_Order.C_Order_ID)
WHERE C_Order.ad_org_id   = 1401007
AND C_order.DOCSTATUS   = 'CO'
AND (TRUNC('1-jul-2014' )     IS NULL
OR C_order.DATEORDERED >= TRUNC('1-jul-2014'))
AND (TRUNC('4-sep-2014')      IS NULL
OR C_order.DATEORDERED <= TRUNC('4-sep-2014'))
ORDER BY c_order.ad_org_id,C_order.DATEORDERED DESC
```

Comment: `TRUNC('4-sep-2014')` relies on implicit data type conversion. Don't do that. Use proper date literals instead. Either ANSI SQL `date `2014-09-04'` or a `to_date()` with a proper format mask that is independent of the client's language: `to_date('2014-09-04', 'yyyy-mm-dd')`

Comment: For a scary example on what relying on implicit data type conversion can do, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25722062/sql-date-calculation-issue

Comment: when i do this its work  : ('1-jul-2014'    IS NULL
OR C_order.DATEORDERED >= '1-jul-2014') but i wen to work it with TRUNK()

Comment: I assume TRUNK() is a typo.  Please correct this.

Comment: `TRUNC('4-sep-2014') IS NULL` doesn't make ***any*** sense. A constant value can *never* be `NULL` - maybe Oracle is smart enough to completely remove this condition.

Comment: Please post the table description!

Comment: its make a sense when user put null date that's only a test because this TRUNC('4-sep-2014') is an user's not obligatory entry  a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: `TRUNC('4-sep-2014')` can **never** be null because `'4-sep-2014'` is not a `NULL` value and will never (even implicitly) converted to a `NULL` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supsect the problem is with your column `DATEORDERED` which is `NUMBER` probably

An example here.

```
SQL>  select * from dual where trunc(to_DATE('04-SEP-2014','DD-MON-YYYY')) > 100;
 select * from dual where trunc(to_DATE('04-SEP-2014','DD-MON-YYYY')) > 100
                                                                      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
```

And this wont throw error. Since, Oracle recognise `04-SEP-2014` as Date

```
SQL> select * from dual where trunc(to_DATE('04-SEP-2014','DD-MON-YYYY')) > '04-SEP-2014';

no rows selected
```

So, you have to analyse the current data in it. Fo any date format it matches with.. 
Something like '`20140409`' -> '`YYYYDDMM`'

And try `TO_DATE(C_order.DATEORDERED,'YYYYDDMM') <= TRUNC(TO_DATE('4-sep-2014','DD-mon-yyyy'))`

Comment: thanks its work with this    TRUNC(TO_DATE(C_order.DATEORDERED,'DD-mon-yyyy')) <= TRUNC(TO_DATE('4-sep-2014','DD-mon-yyyy'))

Comment: @mugiwaradz: the `TRUNC` function is unnecessary around the literal on the right side, since the time component is already guaranteed to be set to midnight. I'd assumed that the datatype of the `DATEORDERD` column was `DATE`, but apparently it's defined as `VARCHAR`, which is very odd. (This answer suggests that the column is defined as NUMBER. But if that was the case, we'd expect the expression you say is working to be throwing an error.

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason to use `trunc()` on a constant like that.  Hey, just use the `date` keyword and specify the dates in ISO standard format:

```
WHERE C_Order.ad_org_id   = 1401007 AND
      C_order.DOCSTATUS   = 'CO' AND
      (DATE '2014-07-01' IS NULL OR C_order.DATEORDERED >= DATE '2014-07-01') AND
      (DATE '2014-09-04' IS NULL OR C_order.DATEORDERED <=  DATE '2014-07-01')
```

If you want to keep your date format, use `to_date('1-jul-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY')` to convert the value to a date.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a `DATE` datatype. That's a string literal. And there's an implicit conversion from VARCHAR to NUMBER. That is, this:

```
TRUNC('1-jul-2014')
```

is equivalent to:

```
TRUNC(TO_NUMBER('1-jul-2014'))
```

<strike>And it's the (implicit) call to the TO_NUMBER function that is throwing the exception.</strike>

And the optimizer is finding a `DATE` on side of a comparison (i.e. a reference to the DATEORDER column), and finding a `NUMBER` on the other side (the result from the expression above.) This "mismatch" in datatypes on either side of the comparison that's causing the error.

---

If you want to return a `DATE` datatype from a string literal, you could use an explicit call to the `TO_DATE` function, using an appropriate format mask, e.g.

```
TO_DATE('1-jul-2014','dd-mon-yyyy')
```

Since time component of the returned `DATE` value will be set to midnight, there's no need for a call to the `TRUNC` function (which would just set the time component to midnight.) But it would be unnecessary, but valid, to wrap that expression in a `TRUNC` function.

Comment: But doesn't this, give a `ORA-01722: invalid number` instead of `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes` ?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar: Good point. What I described would result in an ORA-1722 error at statement *runtime*, and that's not what's happening, the statement isn't getting that far. The ORA-932 is likely being thrown during the statement prepare, the optimizer is finding a DATE on one side of the comparison and a NUMBER on the other side. Good catch. (Actually, the ORA-1722 might also happen at prepare time, since that's a string literal. In any case, the statement is wrong.)